# how to pass struct member into rust macro

Tags: rust, macros

I have following code (which is working fine):

```
for entity in self.entities.iter() {
    let entity_str = normalize_json_for_gdf_agent_serialization(
        &serde_json::to_string_pretty(&entity.file_content)?,
    );
    let file_stem_option = Path::new(&entity.file_name).file_stem();
    if let Some(file_stem) = file_stem_option {
        let mut entity_file_handle = File::create(entities_folder.join(format!(
            "{}{}",
            file_stem.to_str().unwrap(),
            ".json"
        )))?;
        entity_file_handle.write_all(entity_str.as_bytes())?;
    } else {
        return Err(Error::new(format!(
            "Unable to serialize file {}",
            &entity.file_name
        )));
    }
}

for entity_entry in self.entity_entries.iter() {
    let entity_entry_str = normalize_json_for_gdf_agent_serialization(
        &serde_json::to_string_pretty(&entity_entry.file_content)?,
    );
    let file_stem_option = Path::new(&entity_entry.file_name).file_stem();
    if let Some(file_stem) = file_stem_option {
        let mut entity_entry_file_handle = File::create(entities_folder.join(format!(
            "{}{}",
            file_stem.to_str().unwrap(),
            ".json"
        )))?;
        entity_entry_file_handle.write_all(entity_entry_str.as_bytes())?;
    } else {
        return Err(Error::new(format!(
            "Unable to serialize file {}",
            &entity_entry.file_name
        )));
    }
}

for intent in self.intents.iter() {
    let intent_str = normalize_json_for_gdf_agent_serialization(
        &serde_json::to_string_pretty(&intent.file_content)?,
    );
    let file_stem_option = Path::new(&intent.file_name).file_stem();
    if let Some(file_stem) = file_stem_option {
        let mut intent_file_handle = File::create(intents_folder.join(format!(
            "{}{}",
            file_stem.to_str().unwrap(),
            ".json"
        )))?;
        intent_file_handle.write_all(intent_str.as_bytes())?;
    } else {
        return Err(Error::new(format!(
            "Unable to serialize file {}",
            &intent.file_name
        )));
    }
}

for utterance in self.utterances.iter() {
    let utterance_str = normalize_json_for_gdf_agent_serialization(
        &serde_json::to_string_pretty(&utterance.file_content)?,
    );
    let file_stem_option = Path::new(&utterance.file_name).file_stem();
    if let Some(file_stem) = file_stem_option {
        let mut utterance_file_handle = File::create(intents_folder.join(format!(
            "{}{}",
            file_stem.to_str().unwrap(),
            ".json"
        )))?;
        utterance_file_handle.write_all(utterance_str.as_bytes())?;
    } else {
        return Err(Error::new(format!(
            "Unable to serialize file {}",
            &utterance.file_name
        )));
    }
}
```

Lot of repetition, right? I was thinking about macro. Something like:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! serialize_gdf_agent_section {
    ($section:ident, $folder:expr) => {
        for item in $section.iter() {
            let item_str = normalize_json_for_gdf_agent_serialization(
                &serde_json::to_string_pretty(&item.file_content)?,
            );
            let file_stem_option = Path::new(&item.file_name).file_stem();
            if let Some(file_stem) = file_stem_option {
                let mut file_handle = File::create($folder.join(format!(
                    "{}{}",
                    file_stem.to_str().unwrap(),
                    ".json"
                )))?;
                file_handle.write_all(item_str.as_bytes())?;
            } else {
                return Err(Error::new(format!(
                    "Unable to serialize file {}",
                    &item.file_name
                )));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And then calling it like this:

```
serialize_gdf_agent_section!(self.entities, entities_folder);
```

The error I am getting is:

```
error: no rules expected the token `.`
   --> src\gdf_agent.rs:696:42
    |
696 |         serialize_gdf_agent_section!(self.entities, entities_folder);
    |                                          ^ no rules expected this token in macro call
    |
   ::: src\macros.rs:98:1
    |
98  | macro_rules! serialize_gdf_agent_section {
    | ---------------------------------------- when calling this macro

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Any Idea how to make it work?

**self.entities**,  etc is member of struct to be serialized, something like:

```
struct Foo {
  entities: Vec<XYZ>,
  entity_entries: Vec<ABC>
}
```

OK with fresh head I solved it, the solution was to pass whole iterator as expression. ie:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! serialize_gdf_agent_section {
    ($iterator:expr, $folder:expr) => {
        for item in $iterator {
            let item_str = normalize_json_for_gdf_agent_serialization(
                &serde_json::to_string_pretty(&item.file_content)?,
            );
            let file_stem_option = Path::new(&item.file_name).file_stem();
            if let Some(file_stem) = file_stem_option {
                let mut file_handle = File::create($folder.join(format!(
                    "{}{}",
                    file_stem.to_str().unwrap(),
                    ".json"
                )))?;
                file_handle.write_all(item_str.as_bytes())?;
            } else {
                return Err(Error::new(format!(
                    "Unable to serialize file {}",
                    &item.file_name
                )));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

then call like this:

```
serialize_gdf_agent_section!(self.entities.iter(), entities_folder);
serialize_gdf_agent_section!(self.entity_entries.iter(), entities_folder);
serialize_gdf_agent_section!(self.intents.iter(), intents_folder);
serialize_gdf_agent_section!(self.utterances.iter(), intents_folder);
```

Comment: `ident` matches an ident. A single ident. `foo.bar` is an expression.

Comment: ok with fresh had I solved it :) The solution was to provide whole iterator as expression: